# Why isn't Teradata EXCEPT returning expected results?

Tags: sql, join, teradata, diff, except

Why isn't EXCEPT returning expected results? I feel like this should work, but it returns zero rows. However, if I do a count of order-buid-tie rows in T3 that aren't in t2, I get thousands of results and vice versa.

Manual review

```
--first table (T3) without T2 match --178k
select count(*) --178K
from LAB3.Report_stg st3
left join LAB2.Report_stg  st2 
on st3.order_num = st2.order_num and st3.buid= st2.buid and st3.tie_nbr = st2.tie_num
where st2.tie_num is null

--second table (t2) without match in first (T3)
select count(*) --12.5M
from LAB2.Report_stg st2
left join LAB3.Report_stg st3
on st3.order_num = st2.order_num and st3.buid = st2.buid and st3.tie_num = st2.tie_num
where st3.tie_num is null
```

Let's try EXCEPT. I expect 178k rows here and get zero

```
--to avoid cartesian join
--select all mismatched tie_nums
--unless (EXCEPT if) that tie_num exists as a matched set between the two tables
select t3.order_num, t3.buid, t3.tie_num as t3_tie
from LAB3.Report_stg t3
left join LAB2.Report_stg t2
on t3.order_num = t2.order_num and t3.buid = t2.buid and t3.tie_num <> t2.tie_num
except
  (select st3.order_num, st3.buid, st3.tie_num 
  from LAB3.Report_stg st3
  left join LAB2.Report_stg st2
  on st3.order_num = st2.order_num and st3.buid = st2.buid and st3.tie_num = st2.tie_num
  )
```

Comment: Has nothing to do with `EXCEPT`. You changed the predicate from `ON ... st3.tie_nbr = st2.tie_num WHERE st2.Tie_num is null` (anti-join) to `ON ... t3.tie_num <> t2.tie_num` which effectively makes the part prior to `EXCEPT` an inner join instead.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out. The second clause needs to be an INNER JOIN!

Answer (score 0):

Argh, I figured it out! So, the second part of the clause (inside the EXCEPT SELECT) needs to be an INNER JOIN to achieve the desired effect. Again, what I was trying to pull was all the Ties in T3 on the same T2 Orders that don't have a match between the tables.

```
--to avoid cartesian join
--select all mismatched tie_nums
--unless (EXCEPT if) that tie_num exists as a matched set between the two tables
select t3.order_num, t3.buid, t3.tie_num as t3_tie
from LAB3.Report_stg t3
left join LAB2.Report_stg t2
on t3.order_num = t2.order_num and t3.buid = t2.buid and t3.tie_num <> t2.tie_num
except
  (select st3.order_num, st3.buid, st3.tie_num 
  from LAB3.Report_stg st3
  INNER join LAB2.Report_stg st2
  on st3.order_num = st2.order_num and st3.buid = st2.buid and st3.tie_num = st2.tie_num
  )
```

Example:
**T3**
| Order_Num | Tie_Num |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 123 | 1 |
| 123 | 2 |
| 123 | 3 |
| 456   | 1|
| 456   | 4|

**T2**
| Order_Num | Tie_Num |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 123 | 2 |
| 123 | 4 |
| 123 | 5 |
| 456   | 1|
| 456   | 3|

**Results using query above**

**T3**
| Order_Num | Tie_Num |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 123 | 1 |
| 123 | 3 |
| 456   | 4|

So, ideally, I'd union this with an inverse to get the order-ties in T2 that aren't in t3 into the same result set. But then that means I've just written a manual FULL OUTER JOIN
**SMH**